Cannot grant ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY in UI test
My android app uses the ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY permission which is a "special permission" checked through NotificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted. I can't find a way to grant this permission programmatically for a UI test. I have tried
uiAutomation.grantRuntimePermission(
    instrumentation.context.packageName,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY)

but this throws
java.lang.SecurityException: Error granting runtime permission
at android.app.UiAutomation.grantRuntimePermissionAsUser(UiAutomation.java:1574)
at android.app.UiAutomation.grantRuntimePermission(UiAutomation.java:1540)
...
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY requested by package my.package.name is not a changeable permission type

I also found docs for one RuntimePermissionsStubber which looks like it might solve my problem, but the class doesn't seem to actually exist in the espresso-intents package (using version 3.6.1).

This is not a runtime permission, so I doubt that a RuntimePermissionsStubber would help. Have you tried using UiAutomator to automate granting the permission through the Settings app?

@CommonsWare No, I didn't know if that was possible.

Okay, I'm making headway on that. My app opens the settings screen so it's just a few clicks! I've only started learning with espresso up to this point.

"I didn't know if that was possible" -- to be honest, I am not certain if it is. There might be some automation restrictions tied to those sorts of permission grants. Still, IMHO, it is worth pursuing, and I wish you luck!

I was able to navigate the Settings app to allow the permission using UI Automator. It seems like there ought to be an easier solution but oh well. Assuming your app does
startActivity(Intent(ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS))

then in the UI test you can allow the permission with the following:
val instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
val device = UiDevice.getInstance(instrumentation)
device.wait(Until.findObject(By.text("Do Not Disturb access")), 3000)
device.findObject(By.text("Your App Name")).click()
device.wait(Until.findObject(By.text("Allow Do Not Disturb")), 3000).click()
device.wait(Until.findObject(By.text("Allow")), 3000).click()
device.wait(Until.findObject(By.text("Allow Do Not Disturb")), 3000)
device.pressBack()
device.wait(Until.gone(By.text("Allow Do Not Disturb")), 3000)
device.pressBack()

